# Simple image upload via form: how to process errors

Tags: php, html

This is a simple form to upload images. One question, the action pointing to upload_file.php does all the work. If an error is thrown how do I capture this error to display it to the user?

(example taken from http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp)

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT

---

I was not clear enough in this question. The file image_upload.php is passed the $_FILES[] array and there is a lot of error checking which works. The errors are bundled into a JSON array in the php and echo'ed back to the calling page. i.e.

```
echo json_encode(array("error" => $error, "error_desc" => $error_desc, "images" => $images));
```

From the form I need to be able to do something similar to (in pseudo code)

```
if ($error) {
$("#div_error").html("Sorry there was an error " . $error_desc);
}
```

Comment: take a look on $_FILES - http://in1.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: try this tuotorial http://blog.trofeosolution.com/index.php/blog/file-upload

Comment: thanks sundar, but the file-upload solution simple redirects with the error. I need to capture the error and report directly to the same page that is uploading. I.e. user sees an error 'Cannot upload PNG files' for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_FILES['photo']['name'])
{
//if no errors...
if(!$_FILES['photo']['error'])
{
    //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
    $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); //rename file
    if($_FILES['photo']['size'] > (1024000)) //can't be larger than 1 MB
    {
        $valid_file = false;
        $message = 'Oops!  Your file\'s size is to large.';
    }

    //if the file has passed the test
    if($valid_file)
    {
        //move it to where we want it to be
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$new_file_name);
        $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.';
    }
}
//if there is an error...
else
{
    //set that to be the returned message
    $message = 'Ooops!  Your upload triggered the following error:  '.$_FILES['photo']['error'];
}
}

//you get the following information for each file:
$_FILES['field_name']['name']
$_FILES['field_name']['size']
$_FILES['field_name']['type']
$_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name']`
```

refrence from http://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php